# Constraint issue for scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints

So, here is two screens which explains the issue. I have a ScrollView inside a View. And a Lavel + TextField inside the ScrollView. If i'm constraining the Label.leading and TextField.trailing to the ScrollView, then the TextField isn't resized to occupy the entire width. But I found that if I'm constraining them to the external view, then it is resized correctly.

Can someone explain this and is there a better solution to make the TextView to get resized?

(Grayed constrains on the first screen are uninstalled)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your scrollview doesn't know what its contentSize should be because none of the views inside of it have a precise size.

An easy fix would be to place a UIView inside your scrollview, set its leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints to the scroll, set its width to be the same as the viewController's main view and give it a precise height.

Then you can place your label and textfields inside this view.

Comment: Thanks I am understanding the issue now, but in that case my solution is actually better since I'm not introducing a superfluous view. By making the label.leading = safeArea.leading and textField.trailing = safeArea.trailing I'm actually setting the width for content.